Не работает вывод в файл из bashrc
Я хочу на своем сервере на линуксе сделать приветствие для пользователей при входе в него. На сервере есть tsp task spooler для организации очереди задач, и я хочу, чтобы при подключении показывалась текущая очередь задач.
Если просто в /etc/bash.bashrc вставить в начале файле команду tsp, то вместо вывода списка задач выводится только заголовок очереди:
ID   State      Output               E-Level  Times(r/u/s)   Command [run=0/1]
Но самого списка задач нет.
Я зашел с другой стороны и написал микроскрипт, который делает это отдельно и в bashrc прописал команду для его запуска:
tsp > /mnt/d/shared/tsp/tsp_list.txt
echo "текущие задачи tsp:"
cat /mnt/d/shared/tsp/tsp_list.txt

Если просто запускать этот файл из консоли - всё работает, но если он запускается при входе из bashrc, то скрипт запускается, но опять в tsp_list.txt записался только заголовок.
С чем такие приколы могут быть связаны?
Дополнение: Почему-то такое происходит только при первичном логине к серверу. При смене пользователя все работает как надо...

переменные окружения разные. попробуйте с чистым окружением запустить: $ env -i команда аргументы
